# Overriding CSS of webpages

Tags: css, ubuntu, overriding, kde-plasma

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` with default Gnome 3 Desktop and 2 weeks ago I decided to install KDE instead. But it was so hard for me so I decided to switch back to Ubuntu. But while I was using KDE, I changed something in the font part in the settings so that now some websites are displaying in that font (like Wikipedia but Google, Youtube or StackOverflow not). So now I'm having 2 questions:

1. Are there any way to reset it back so that the CSS is not overridden?
2. How to override CSS on more (web)sites?

---

I'm a total Linux-newbie. It would be very good of you if you give me some explaination.
Also, there could be some grammar error here. My English is not so good

Comment: You probably changed your default fonts when you installed KDE. Change them back to Ubuntu.

Comment: I deleted it unfortunately